# Python interpreter crash on shut down

Tags: python, windows, crash

I'm in the process of retro-fitting graceful shut down in a legacy Python application that hosts SWIGged a (very) large C++ extension module.  I'm getting a crash during interpreter shut down and I'm out of ideas, so I'm hoping you can help me out to figure the cause.

So here's the information I've collected so far:

- Running Python 2.7.2, 32-bits on Windows;
- all C++ threads started by the application are (AFAICT) closed and joined properly;
- all Python threads started by the application are (AFAICT) closed and joined properly (they are marked as daemons to avoid hanging as a last resort, but they are all joined);
- Process Explorer (Sysinternals) shows a small number of threads with a "start address" at `ntdll.dll!TpCallbackIndependent+0x238`;
- Process Explorer shows one thread with a "start address" at `ntdll.dll!RtlMoveMemory+x5a5`;
- When the application exits (after successfully joining all threads), the threads in `ntdll.dll` are still running and the exit status is 1;
- By the time this happens, all my logging and diagnostics facilities are closed.

This `TpCallbackIndependent` thing seems related to the [Windows Thread Pool API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686766.aspx), which is **not** used by this application.  I can list all external Python libraries if it means anything to you, but I don't think any of them uses it either.

---

**Edit**: Possible culprit is `pycurl` module.  As soon as I issue my first `pycurl.Curl.perform()`, the `RtlMoveMemory` and `mswsock` threads start up.  Even if I call `pycurl.global_cleanup()` (at which point the `mswsock` thread disappears, the `RtlMoveMemory` thread never completes and `TpCallbackIndependent` spuriously appear and disappear forever after that.

`pycurl.version` prints "libcurl/7.20.1 OpenSSL/0.9.8q zlib/1.2.5" and I have no idea what the `pycurl` version is (I only have the `.pyd` file).

---

**Edit**: here is a sample Pycurl program that creates the problematic threads.  For some reason I can't explain, this particular invocation doesn't crash though...

```
import cStringIO
import pycurl
import sys

pycurl.global_init(pycurl.GLOBAL_DEFAULT)
try:
    b = cStringIO.StringIO()
    # Issue request.
    c = pycurl.Curl()
    try:
        c.setopt(pycurl.CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET')
        c.setopt(c.URL, 'http://www.google.ca')
        c.setopt(c.WRITEFUNCTION, b.write)

        print 'Type anything to issue the request.'
        sys.stdin.readline()
        c.perform()

        # Threads appear as a result of the `.perform()`
        # operation.  If you monitor the active threads
        # in "process explorer", you see that the threads
        # appear here.
    finally:
        c.close()
        del c
finally:
    print 'Type anything to cleanup.'
    sys.stdin.readline()
    pycurl.global_cleanup()

# If you're still looking at active threads in "process
# explorer", you see that some threads (the mswsock.dll
# thread in particular) have disappeared, but there are still
# weird TpCallbackIndependent threads showing up.

print 'Type anything to exit.'
sys.stdin.readline()
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure all pycurl objects are closed before you call cleanup. This includes easy, share and multi objects.

Comment: Yes, I have explicitly closed all `pycurl.Curl` objects using their `.close()` method.  In addition, explicitly `del ...`eting them doesn't help.

Comment: Next thing to do would be to upgrade pycurl and libcurl. You are using a very old version of libcurl and your pycurl is probably at least a couple of versions old.

Comment: Try to confirm or eliminate pycurl as the responsible party. Does the crash happen in every single application invocation? Does the app have to make network requests to crash? Do requests have to be specific ones? Consider replacing pycurl with urllib for debugging purposes.

Comment: I can confirm the spawned thread pool things are somehow the result of Pycurl.  I have a sample program that issues a single Pycurl request and you can see the threads come up as soon as the fist `pycurl.Curl.perform()`.  I'll post sample code.  Unfortunately, updating Pycurl on Windows is a real pain in the neck  and will cause compatibility problems in our application.  I'll see if I can accurately determine _what_ causes the crash before I update Pycurl.